# Using UIAddressBook with TabBar and Navigation Controller

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uinavigationcontroller

I want to use UIAddressBook with a TabBar and a Navigation Controller.

How do I go about this.

Please help.

edit
I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and when I use this by presentModalViewController it covers whole the screen ,I also used some Tabbar it covers that ,but I want to show that Tabbar

Comment: Reply please if any one knows

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you would like to do?

Comment: Hi phoose, I am using ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and when I use this by presentModalViewController it covers whole the screen ,I also used some Tabbar it covers that ,but I want to show that Tabbar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple.

```
picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
// place the delegate of the picker to the control
picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
picker.view.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view addSubview:picker.view];
```

The trick is to set the frame to self.view.bounds; that did it for me; it makes it appear within the two controllers.